# API Requires Static IP Addresses but I use a CDN

Tags: javascript, json, http, cdn, http-get

I am looking to use a JSON API that requires that I enter a set of specific IP addresses to allow access to in order to obtain an API key. However, I use a web host that uses a CDN (It should also be noted that I cannot modify any server-side code), so I cannot get a static IP address for my website's server. Is there any way for me to get around this? Is there a way for me make the GET requests to the API through a server with a static IP address that will then relay the request response to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup an reverse proxy on a server with static IP for that (e.g use NGINX). You can easily find some examples on Google like [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/)

Comment: I know basically nothing about back-end. Are there any cloud hosting services that I can use to simply set this up? I already have a CDN, so I don't want to pay for the whole NGINX service. I just want the reverse proxy part.

Comment: In fact, it's very simple to install NGINX on Linux Virtual Machine (it's free) and it requires a very basic configuration for the server (e.g 2 cores, 4GB Ram) so I recommend you to try this option.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I mean you can use a Linux VPS (e.g Ubuntu Server) for this. It's very cheap. After that, you can install nginx by 

`sudo apt-get install nginx`

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the service that you recommend? I don't want to pay for hosting when all I want is the one reverse proxy redirect.

Comment: In fact, I usually use Azure or AWS. You can visit http://azure.microsoft.com or aws.amazon.com. You event can use a free server at AWS if all you need is just proxy pass

Comment: Which service on AWS would that be?

Comment: I've spent the day trying to get a simple reverse proxy set up. I have followed numerous tutorials for AWS reverse proxy solutions, but none have worked. I also looked into Microsoft Azure, but it costs $57.29/month for a Ubuntu VPS which seems extremely expensive for just a redirect.

Comment: Hi, 

Please try AWS EC2 t2.micro VPS which is FREE If what you need is just reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The "server with a static IP address" you need is named a reverse-proxy server.

You can install such a server on any cloud Linux or Windows instance: just install Apache according to the following documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html